# Find the index of a value (with approximation) in Python list

Tags: python

I have a Python list and I want to find the index of the closer value in it.

What I have done until now:

```
value = 3.5
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(0,len(mylist)+2):
    if value > mylist[i] and value < mylist[i+1]:
        if abs(mylist[i]-value) < abs(mylist[i+1]-value):
              myindex = mylist.index(i)
        else:
              myindex = mylist.index(i+1)
        break
```

The list is sorted without dublicates, so if I find one index, it will be the right one.

Do you know if there is any build-in method to do it or a library that will do this faster than my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your list is sorted, you can use the `bisect` module's [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) function, like this

```
value, mylist = 3.5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
from bisect import bisect
print bisect(mylist, value)
# 3
```

This will give you the index at which the element fits in the list and this will be faster (O lg N) than the liner searching (O (N)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) like this.

```
value, mylist = 3.5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
from itertools import takewhile
print sum(1 for i in takewhile(lambda x: x < value, mylist))
# 3
```

Comment: That has same complexity as the OPs :-)